# Laptop suddenly lags making computer unusable

Tags: laptop, cpu-usage

Yesterday, after playing **Team Fortress 2** for around *20 minutes*, my computer (an [HP Compaq 8510p laptop](http://www.notebookreview.com/default.asp?newsID=3939)) started lagging so bad I couldn't even shut down the game, I couldn't move the cursor nor could I run the task manager.
At first I blamed it on my wireless internet connection, but when I saw my brother playing the same game with no problems I got suspicious.

I rebooted my computer and everything worked perfectly. I decided to try playing another [steam-game](http://www.steampowered.com), **Counter-Strike: Source**, but sadly the same thing happened again after around *15-20 minutes*.

I read [this thread](http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-xp/computer-lags-up-for-no-reason/145839.html) on another website, but since my problem has never occured before, I figured it was irrelevant. Besides that, I have already cleansed my computer using all the standard Windows 7 cleaning-utilities, like the defragmenter, and followed most of the advices on [that page](http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-xp/computer-lags-up-for-no-reason/145839.html).

I've repeatedly tried to fix this on my own, like closing all background applications and running the games again, but with the same result.
I also ran a full computer check using F-Secure, a small malware-file was found, but was instantly removed. This didn't help neither.

If I could open the task manager after the computer acts retarded, I would've linked a screenshot of the task manager, but since I can't open it, this is impossible.

Have any of you experienced the same problem? If so, how did you fix this?

In case you "need" it, here are some informations about my laptop:

- **CPU:** Intel Core2 Duo with 2.0 GHz pr.
  core (which was quite a lot for a laptop back when I bought it 2 years ago)
- **Ram:** 2 GB
- **OS:** Windows 7 Home Premium
- **Cooling:** Very poor fan, has a hard time cooling my laptop and is very noisy and needs to be cleaned very often

Comment: have you checked the temperature of your gpu and cpu while this happens?

Comment: No, is this a thing to do manually you know with a thermometer or is it measured inside the computer somewhere?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=temperature+monitoring+software

Comment: you will need some tool for that like everest home edition (http://www.lavalys.com/) it´s also possible to see the temperature of at least the cpu at your BIOS.

Comment: *Very poor fan, has a hard time cooling my laptop and is very noisy and needs to be cleaned very often* - Explains - if the temps increase beyond safe limits the processor is throttled to avoid damage

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try running it with the "case" open, if possible on your laptop.

Comment: to reduce the heat?

Comment: Alternatively, try a cooling pad.

Answer (score -1):

look to see if there are any screws loose, check the temperature, any programs taking up too much RAM might be the problem as well, if the problem persists, then go to your local computer store. (not geeksquad)